# how to display an image with android

Tags: android

in my activity i have two spinners. based on first spinner, second spinner has to change. i am getting it. but the problem is when i am selecting the item in second spinner the appropriate image is not getting displayed.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{
ImageView im;
Object result,result1;
String[] country = { "Birds", "Countries", "Cars","Animals"};

String[] Birds_Birds = { "parrot", "peacock", "Sparrow","Pigeon"};
String[]items={"b1","b2","b3","b4"};
int[] imgIds={R.drawable.b1,R.drawable.b2,R.drawable.b3,R.drawable.b4};
String[] Countries_Countries = { "India", "Pakistan", "libya","Dubai"};
String[] Cars_Cars = { "Benz", "BMW", "Skoda","Ambassador"};
String[] Animals_Animals = { "Tiger", "leopard", "Horse","Rabbit"};

int fee,tot=0,atot=0;
Spinner spin0,spin1;


String Name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //EditText display1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    spin0 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spin0.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
    ArrayAdapter <String> c = new ArrayAdapter <String>      
  (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
    c.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin0.setAdapter(c);


    spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
    spin1.setEnabled(false);


   }
   @SuppressWarnings("null")
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

    if(arg0.equals(spin0)){

            spin1.setEnabled(true);
                        if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("Birds"))
                        {
                            ArrayAdapter <String> s1 = new ArrayAdapter <String>    
     (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Birds_Birds);
    s1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spin1.setAdapter(s1);
                            AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> parent = null;
                            int pos = 0;

      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                            switch (pos) {
                            case 0:
                                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.b1);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.b2);         
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.b3);         
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }


                        }

                     result1=spin1.getSelectedItem();
                     result=spin0.getSelectedItem();

                   // display1.setText(""+result +"     /    "+result1); 



    }    
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {                

    }
   }
```

Comment: im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));

Comment: hey tara, you didnt gave me response yaar....wats goin on?

Comment: @Pratik u dint gave me the email id. with that how can i forward?

Comment: @Tara check your previous post, I have given it before 3 hours dear.

Comment: @Tara noted it down still or not?

Comment: yup noted. thnak u vry much.

Answer (score 1):

When you select an item in `spin1` nothing is done because you have done

`if(arg0.equals(spin0)){`

and this will only be true when any item from the `sp0` is selected.

If you select an item from `sp1` this will be false and as a result nothing will happen.

If you want to do anything on the item select of `sp1` add an `else` part